# Vector addition to rotation matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Let’s say I have $3×3$ rotation matrices $A$ and $B$, is there a matrix operation that is equivalent to converting them to Euler vectors $a$ and $b$ and adding $a+b$, since $a+b$ is different from $AB$?

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation  You can use exponential map or quaternions.

Comment: I tried axis angle and quaternion but both did not give what I wanted. Matrix multiplication is isomorphic to quaternion multiplication, but is not the same as vector addition. I'm also not sure how to go from Euler to exponential map.

Comment: What are you asking for? A matrix, which converts a rotation matrix into an Euler vector? My intuition tells me this won’t exist, as the conversion from cartesian to polar coordinates is not linear and involves trigonometric functions. Why should your matrix also add these two vectors? Note that matrix multiplication is usually considered a unary operation and not a binary operation, so you cannot handle both Euler angles at once unless you hack around this by increasing the dimensions of your matrix and inputs...

Comment: I’m asking because I found that when rotating some Euler angle a by an Euler angle b with XYZ ordering, you can in fact recreate gimbal lock with quaternions and matrices by premultiplying rotations on the X axis (either matrix or Quaternion multiplication because they are isomorphic), and post-multiplying rotations on the Z axis. However, the Y axis is slightly different between adding Euler angles and converting to a rotation matrix and pre or post-multiplying. Either way, if you move Y axis to the poles +/- 90 degrees you can recreate gimbal lock.

Comment: This is all good I do not have a problem with recreating gimbal lock where desired. What’s not good is that to recreate the motion of rotating on Y (pitch) a is the only solution I can see if your rotation is in Quaternion or matrix is to convert back to Euler, then add or subtract, then convert back to Quaternion or matrix. I simply wondered if there was a pure Quaternion or matrix operation that would do effectively the same without conversion.

Comment: *I meant to say motion of rotating on Y as if by adding or subtracting Euler angles, rather than by pre or post multiplying rotation matrices or quaternions since they are different as I’ve tested.

Comment: @PrudiiArca I have figured out the answer on my own it looks like and will post as soon as I have done some testing. It would appear that if I take an XYZ ordered matrix (that is, the Y is the pitch angle), if I premultiply the X and postmultiply the Z, it is almost the same as adding vectors, except you need to cover the Y also, which cannot be pre or post multiplied using the commonly known matrices. The solution appears to be close to an XYX multiplication when premultiplying and ZYZ when postmultiplying, except there are some sign flips. This is very interesting.

Comment: I am sorry. Your comments were not pushed forward to me, so I didn’t notice. I am glad you could figure it out!

Comment: Thanks! I’ll post the answer soon here.